# How to free structure xmlSAXHandler from Libxml2 library

Tags: c++, c, xml, libxml2, memory-management

I created a SAX validator by using libxml2 library.

Here is How I created it:

```
void OnStartElementNs(
    void *ctx,
    const xmlChar *localname,
    const xmlChar *prefix,
    const xmlChar *URI,
    int nb_namespaces,
    const xmlChar **namespaces,
    int nb_attributes,
    int nb_defaulted,
    const xmlChar **attributes) {}

void OnEndElementNs(
    void* ctx,
    const xmlChar* localname,
    const xmlChar* prefix,
    const xmlChar* URI) {}

void OnCharacters(void *ctx, const xmlChar *ch, int len) 
{
    char chars[len + 1];
    strncpy(chars, (const char *)ch, len);
    chars[len] = '\0';
}

xmlSAXHandler make_sax_handler ()
{
    xmlSAXHandler SAXHander;

    memset(&SAXHander, 0, sizeof(xmlSAXHandler));

    SAXHander.initialized = XML_SAX2_MAGIC;
    SAXHander.startElementNs = OnStartElementNs;
    SAXHander.endElementNs = OnEndElementNs;
    SAXHander.characters = OnCharacters;

    return SAXHander;
}

xmlSAXHandler mySAXHandler = make_sax_handler();
```

So I got a xmlSAXHandler object, if I want to free the memory, I can free each variables saparately, like using xmlFree(xmlChar*). I'm new to XML and libxml2, so I'm wondering whether there is a convenient way to free the whole structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manage the allocation of the `xmlSAXHandler` struct yourself. libxml2 doesn't provide functions to do that. In your example, you return a pointer to a stack-allocated struct. This can't work and will probably make your program crash at some point. To make your code work correctly, you should allocate the `xmlSAXHandler` struct on the heap using `malloc` and free it using `free` when you no longer need it.